# If the partial limits of two sequences are equals then the sequences equals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I didn't understand something about partial limits of sequences:

Say there are two series - $a_n , b_n$. Its unknown if they converge.

Is it right to say that if the partial limits of the two series are equal to each other then the series are equal ? 
What about the other way around - if the series are equal then the partial limits are equal? 
The first one seem wrong to me but I can't find an example to contradict it.

What about if they are only equal from a certain point? meaning - There is an $N$ that for every $n>N : a_n=b_n$ ? Does it changes the answer for any of the claims?

Just started learning about limits last month,

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Please [edit] the title to something more descriptive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it right to say that if the partial limits of the two series are equal to each other then the series are equal ?

No, not at all. For example, the limits (and therefore all partial limits) of $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $(0)$ coincide, but the sequences clearly are not equal.

> What about the other way around - if the series are equal then the partial limits are equal?

Yes, this is obvious. The (partial) limits of $(a_n)$ are the partial limits of $(a_n)$.

> What about if they are only equal from a certain point? meaning - There is an $N$ that for every $n>N:a_n=b_n$ ? Does it changes the answer for any of the claims?

No: for the first, the counterexample above still works. For the second, yes, you can change the first finitely-many terms of a sequence without changing its limiting behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!